# A class written in JS is exported (module.export) How can I use it into an html script in javascript?

Tags: html, node.js, class, import

I have a class written in Javascript.
This class is in a file : Parcours.js.

```
module.exports = class Parcours {
constructor(componentList) {
    this.components = componentList;
    this.length = componentList.length;
    this.current = 0; // We start at the first component.
}

next () { // my next function
...
```

I test this class with chai :

```
const Parcours = require('../app/Parcours');
const expect = require('chai').expect;

describe('Parcours', () => {
describe('Test empty page list', () => {
    it('Constructor : Empty page list should give a zero length, an empty component list and a current to be zero', () => {
        const parcours = new Parcours([]);
        expect(parcours.length).to.equal(0);
        expect(parcours.current).to.equal(0);
...
```

It works well. Everything is good.

Now, I would like to use this class into an HTML page. I would like to instanciate this class into an object "parcours".

For that, first  I have a div :

```
<div hidden='true' id='adjustment-panel'>
<input type='submit' id='previous-ajustment' value='Précédent' onclick='parcours.next()' />
<label for='adjustment'>Ajustement : </label>
...
```

The parcours.next is a call to the 'next' method for the parcours instanciaiton of the class Parcours.

My problem is : I don't know how to

1. Import the Parcours class into my HTML script tag
2. How to instanciate the class Parcours into an object 'parcours'
3. how to use it in the DOM events onclick (or any other)

What I tried :
I included the class in my body scripts with :

```
    <script type='module' src='./app/Parcours.js'></script>
    <script>
        const Etapes = ['player-panel', 'adjustment-panel','target-panel'];
        const parcours = new Parcours(Etapes);
    </script>
```

But the result is :

`(index):45 Uncaught ReferenceError: Parcours is not defined at (index):45`

Where index:45 is the line where I use parcours.next() in onclick event:

```
    <input type='submit' id='previous-ajustment' value='Précédent' onclick='parcours.next()' />
```

Can you provide me a good way to do this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found !

Use the modules ECMASCRIPT 6

My class is now expoerted in a Parcours.mjs file :

```
export class Parcours {
    constructor(componentList) {
...
```

I import it in my chai file test, wich becomes also a .mjd file

```
import { Parcours } from '../public/scripts/Parcours.mjs';
import pkg from 'chai';
const { expect } = pkg;

describe('Parcours', () => {
...
```

The tests works fine again.

And, in my HTML file, I used the import correctly (I hope) :

```
<script type='module'>
    import { Parcours } from './Parcours.mjs'
    const Etapes = ['player-panel', 'adjustment-panel','target-panel'];
    window.parcours = new Parcours(Etapes);
</script>
```

and everything works fine !

Thank you everyone who looked at it !